# I have 8 of those for a hotel safe all need to be refills and teste it so please how can i do that?

Tags: fire-hazard, fire-extinguisher

[image]

How can I refill them?
where can I refill them and teste them too?
how much will cost me for refill ?
how much will cost generally ?

Comment: Why have you posted the same [question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/157412/refill-of-fire-extinguisher) twice?

Answer (score 2):

You don't refill them. You replace them if they are past their date. Basically you physically inspect them. Or you take them to a fire extinguisher place to be checked. If it is a hotel, you need to have these professionally inspected at least once a year.

Comment: I thought commercial facility's had to inspect every 30 days. I know osha looks to verify they are getting checked.

Comment: Much agreed. @Ed Beal. At a restaurant I worked in years ago, they inspected quarterly, at the logistics facility I worked at, they inspected them every 6 months. Either way, they should be professionally inspected and tagged.

Answer (score 2):

Check with your local fire station. I know the main station in my town refills extinguishers. Other companies that certify high pressure tanks (hydrostatic testing) also fill extinguishers. Both places I know of have fire in there name.

Comment: Thank you yes I already did inspect it but I have extra I need to refill them for safety but I thought I can get or find local commercial contact I guess I am wrong to find it here.